# Add byte[] to ZipFile as file.jpg with HttpResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse

**I've got this code snipped that download successfully:**

```
byte[] bytes;
bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(lehrling.passfoto);
Response.Clear();
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + lehrling.vorname + "." + lehrling.nachname + ".jpeg");
Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
Response.End()
```

This works just fine. I get a jpeg file out of it.  Now:

**I created a for-loop that executes the code shown above for each bytearray:**

```
    for (int i = 0; i < anzahlBilder; i++)
    {
         //My Code here
    }
    Response.End()
```

I get `anzahlBilder` from somewhere else. its not important for my question. I put `Response.End()` outside of my for-loop because otherwise it ends after 1 `image` got downloaded.

**To Zip:**

Now i want to create a .Zip file, which contains all my images. I dont know how to do it. Any Suggestions?

Comment: [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: yes, but what do i write as parameters in my example? could you provide a code sample ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx)

You need to add a dll reference to the assembly, "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll" and import namespace.

```
System.IO.Compression
```

at the top.

```
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile();
    for(int i = 0; i < anzahlBilder; i++)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms= new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(lehrling.passfoto)))
        {
            Image userImage = Image.FromStream(ms);   
            userImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);  
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            byte[] imageData = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Read(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
            zipFile.AddEntry(lehrling.vorname + "." + lehrling.nachname + ".jpeg", imageData);
        }
    }

    zipFile.Save(Response.OutputStream);
```

make required changes in place of `lehrling.passfoto` and `lehrling.vorname + "." + lehrling.nachname + ".jpeg"` to get it work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i can create a ZipFile instance thoe. It sais it must be convertible to System.IDisponsable, any idea why?

Comment: Which line?____

Comment: what do i set as tempstream ?

Comment: not working either, it sais it cant be defined like that

Comment: What is exact message?

Comment: the type, used in a using statement must be convertible to idisponsable. the error when i try with updated code is: ZipFile cannot be defined

Comment: please paste exact error after using updated code. What you are mentioning is not dotnet error

Comment: What .net version you are using?

Comment: i am using .net 4.5.2 / the exact message is: cannot create an instance of the static class ZipFile

Comment: i know why i am getting this error...... can you change your answer from ZipFile - Class to ZipArchive - Class and adjust the code... so i can mark as answered

Comment: check updated answer, just import dll and use reference in code

Comment: If you are naming the file `.jpeg` why are you useing `ImageFormat.Png`?

Comment: @MatthewWhited nice catch

Comment: and if you just want the byte array from the `MemoryStream` just call `.ToArray()`

Comment: i've already done that. not the reference is the problem. i think its my .net version. can you provide code with the ZipArchive class. that one works, but i dont know how to adjust the code to get it to work @Imad

Comment: Its fine if your code is working, you can post it as your own answer :)

Comment: there is not even a .AddEntry for the ZipFile class @Imad